# Injective Linear Maps Deform the Sphere Continuously

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}\newcommand{\R}{\mathbf R}$
Let $\mc L^*(\R^k, \R^n)$ denote the set of all the injective lineat maps from $\R^k$ into $\R^n$ and $f:\R\to \mc L^*(\R^k, \R^n)$ be a continuous map.

> **Claim.** Then there is an $\varepsilon>0$ and a $\delta>0$ such that $B(0, \varepsilon)\cap f_t(S^{k-1})=\emptyset$ whenever $|t|< \delta$, where we write $f_t$ to denote the linear map $f(t)$.

Here is my argument. Let $I=[-1, 1]$ and define $K=f(I)$.
Then $K$ is a compact set in $\mc L^*(\R^k, \R^m)$. Now assume on the contrary that the claim is false.
Then for all $n>0$ there is $t_n\in \R$ with  $|t_n|<1/n$ such that $|T_n(u_n)|<1/n$ for some $u_n\in S^{k-1}$, where $T_n=f(t_n)$.
Since all the $T_n$'s are in $K$, there is a $T\in K$ to which a subsequence of $(T_n)$ converges.
Without loss of generality we may assume that $(T_n)$ itself converges to $T$.
Further, since $S^{k-1}$ is compact, there is a $u\in S^{k-1}$ to which $(u_n)$ converges.
Again, we may assume that $(u_n)$ itself converges to $u$.
Now in $|T_nu_n|< 1/n$, we take $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ to get $|Tu|=0$.
But then $T$ is not injective which is a contradiction.

Is the claim and the argument correct? If yes,

> Is there a way to prove the claim neatly, preferably without using the sequence approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof looks good to me.

An outline for an alternative proof: define $g\ :\ \Bbb R \times \Bbb R^k \to \Bbb R^n\ :\ (t, x) \mapsto f_t(x)$. $g$ is then continuous. $T := [-1,1]\times S^{k-1}$ is compact. Since for all $t, f_t$ is injective and $f_t(0) = 0$, we know that $0 \notin f_t(S^{k-1})$, so $0 \notin g(T)$. Since $g(T)$ is compact, it is closed, and therefore there exists a ball $B(0,\epsilon)$ about $0$ such that $B(0,\epsilon) \cap g(T) = \emptyset$.

I note that neither of our proofs shows any need to restrict $\delta$.

Comment: This does it much more neatly. Exactly what I was looking for.